# how to solve Django " TypeError at /auth/users/ create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username' " in case of default user model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

When I request to create a user using djoser Endpoint `/user/`. But it says `create_user() missing 1 required positional .argument: 'username'` I have searched on Google and all are related to custom user model but I haven't touched user model. I am using postman to post the request and I am passing the username as you can see below:
[image: of postman]
I don't know where the problem lies and what to change.
I have also changed "username" to "name" but it did not work.
Any help would be highly appreciated .Thank you very much ❤️❤️❤️.

I will show you what you will ask me to show.

Comment: I have searched in google but all have custom user model while I haven't.

Comment: Did you modify any user managers?

Comment: No I didn't.  Its all built in,.

Answer (score 0):

Is your 'LOGIN_FIELD' in your Djoser settings set to 'email' by any chance? If so, try changing it to 'username' so that create_user takes in the username instead of an email.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).